# Does the delivery of BMP-12,-13,-14 (either in form of a gene or a protein) into an injured tendon help improve healing in humans?

Tags: tendinopathy, treatment, tendons

I have read that delivery of BMP-12,-13,-14 (either in form of a gene or a protein) into an injured tendon improved healing, but I haven't been able yet to find an in-vivo study in humans confirming it.

For example, the 2007 {1} study showed that BMP-14 gene therapy increases tendon tensile strength in a rat model of Achilles tendon injury:

> The results of this animal study suggest that gene therapy with BMPs may improve the capacity of injured musculoskeletal tissue to heal.

The 2001 study {2} was tested on chickens:

> We conclude that BMP-12 gene transfer is a promising procedure for improving the tendon repair process.

The 1999 study {3} was tested on rats:

> The rats were killed after 2 weeks and the tensile strength of the tendon regenerate was found to be increased by both proteins in a seemingly dose-dependent manner.

The 2019 study {5} was tested on rabbits:

> Rotator cuff regeneration achieved by BMP-12-overexpressing BM-MSCs-loaded PLGA scaffolds may represent a novel approach for the management of rotator cuff defect.

The 2017 study {4} was tested on humans but it  was in vitro:

> BMP-12 activates tenogenic pathway in hASCs but also affects secretory activity and impairs immunomodulatory potential of this population that can influence the clinical outcome after cell transplantation.

Does the delivery of BMP-12,-13,-14 (either in form of a gene or a protein) into an injured tendon help improve healing in humans?

---

References:

- {1} Bolt P, Clerk AN, Luu HH, Kang Q, Kummer JL, Deng ZL, Olson K, Primus F, Montag AG, He TC, et al. BMP-14 gene therapy increases tendon tensile strength in a rat model of Achilles tendon injury. J Bone Joint Surg Am. 2007;89(6):1315–20. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17545436?dopt=Abstract
- {2} Lou J, Tu Y, Burns M, Silva MJ, Manske P. BMP-12 gene transfer augmentation of lacerated tendon repair. J Orthop Res. 2001;19(6):1199–202. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11781024?dopt=Abstract
- {3} Aspenberg P, Forslund C. Enhanced tendon healing with GDF 5 and 6. Acta Orthop Scand. 1999;70(1):51–4. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10191749?dopt=Abstract ; https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Enhanced%20tendon%20healing%20with%20GDF%205%20and%206&journal=Acta%20Orthop%20Scand&volume=70&issue=1&pages=51-4&publication_year=1999&author=Aspenberg%2CP&author=Forslund%2CC
- {4} Zarychta-Wiśniewska, Weronika, Anna Burdzinska, Agnieszka Kulesza, Kamila Gala, Beata Kaleta, Katarzyna Zielniok, Katarzyna Siennicka, Marek Sabat, and Leszek Paczek. "Bmp-12 activates tenogenic pathway in human adipose stem cells and affects their immunomodulatory and secretory properties." BMC cell biology 18, no. 1 (2017): 13. https://doi.org/10.1186/s12860-017-0129-9
- {5} Chen, Peng, Lei Cui, Guofei Chen, Tian You, Wei Li, Jianwei Zuo, Chen Wang, Wentao Zhang, and Changqing Jiang. "The application of BMP-12-overexpressing mesenchymal stem cells loaded 3D-printed PLGA scaffolds in rabbit rotator cuff repair." International journal of biological macromolecules (2019). https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31295489

Comment: I hope that one day we will get an orthopedic surgeon who is well versed in the literature on these niche questions to visit us and answer them.  I would definitely be interested.

Comment: @DoctorWhom I hope so. If you're interested in reading an answer to a question, you might want to consider upvoting the question, as otherwise the question might get automatically deleted (see [39 questions of mine deleted, and counting. How do you expect users to write well written questions?](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/939/43)). Having one's questions deleted simply because nobody upvoted the question is probably not a great way to convince experts to spend their time here by the way. I personally wouldn't advise anyone to use such a website.

Comment: Point taken and done!